# Can I grant database permission on a login object?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to grant create database permission to a login because the login owns the database and there is no user. My question is what's the default user if the login owns the database and is not mapped to an explicit user?

Comment: Is the true question how to map a server login to a db user? i.e. do you have an orphaned user?

Comment: Yes, would I need to create a new user for each login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a login has permission to `CREATE` a database (perhaps they have the `dbcreator` role) then when the database is created the user `dbo` will be mapped to their login.

Comment: The login does not have permission to create a database.

Comment: @HaydenH Why did you eit the answer to say it isn't helpful, yet mark it as a solution? They are quite different actions. There's not a lot of description in your question, hence the short answer. I think you need to expand on your question and explain better.

Comment: I never marked the answer as a solution and the question seems concise.

Comment: Only the OP of a question can mark an answer as the solution @HaydenH, so only you can mark it as the answer.